# castlemock fails to find ports, with svc wsdl

Tags: .net, mocking, wsdl

Using castlemock to mock a wsdl end point.

I upload my wsdl, and it fails to find any ports.  the wsdl (...svc?singlewsdl) does not, indeed, have any wsdl:port elements.  It has instead:

```
 <wsdl:portType name="IMyService">
      <wsdl:operation name="GetServiceStatus">
         <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/GetServiceStatus" message="tns:IMyService_GetServiceStatus_InputMessage" />
         <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IMyService/GetServiceStatusResponse" message="tns:IMyService_GetServiceStatus_OutputMessage" />
      </wsdl:operation>
```

Is this not valid in castlemock?